# Combining a dataframe with multiple rows to another dataframe with a single row based on a column row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe say :

```
A | B
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
```

and another one like :

```
A  |  G
1     Gate
```

and i want to combine the first dataframe with the other dataframe such that it shows :

```
A  | B   |   G
1    a    Gate
2    b     
3    c
4    d
```

I have not been able to create the new column using `pd.merge` and i am new to python/pandas. Any help would be appreciated.

Another condition i failed to mention was that the dataframe with one row can have multiple changes since it is in a loop and the variables keep changing.

So,

```
A  |  G
1    Gate
```

could be

```
A  | H
2    Gate 2
```

or

```
A |  F     
4   gate 4
```

So the final output would say :

```
A  |  B  |  G  |   H   |  F |
1     a    Gate
2     b         Gate 2  
3     c
4     d                  Gate 4
```

At the end of this loop i would like to write this output to an excel file using 
`pd.to_excel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to use merge, you can do a left join like this:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='A')
```

Comment: Please remove your answer because dupe, maybe find some better one.

Comment: What if the dataframe with a single row is in a for loop and it keeps updating the that one row... Also what if the column name changes as well? will the merge work for all the times? I can update my question.

Comment: @jezrael i can add this into my questions then it wont be a dupe?

Comment: It depends what add, if no dupe please give me know I can reopen. Tte best is add [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain why dupe does not work.

Comment: @jezrael Could you have a look at the question. I just edited it...

Comment: Unfortunately need map solution from duplicated answer :(

Comment: @jezrael could you please elaborate what a map solution from duplicated answer means. Thank You.

Comment: Sure. So need `d1 = df2.set_index('A')['G'].to_dict()
df1['G'] = df1['A'].map(d1)`, `d2 = df3.set_index('A')['H'].to_dict()
df1['H'] = df1['A'].map(d2)`. Explanation - create dict with each new one row df and map to new column.

Comment: @jezrael Thank you! Could you also please tell me how would you write this dict to the base excel sheet ? Is it after creating the dictionary completely or after inserting each new key in the dictionary? Sorry, this is my first time.

Comment: @jezrael the base excel sheet has the column A and B and i would like to add the new columns to that sheet with the A in one dataframe matching the other dataframe.

Comment: Hmmm, you create new datagrame columns by map, get finsl dataframe with columns A,B,G,H,F and then write dataframe to excel. There is no write dictionary to excel.

Comment: @jezrael alright!I will try and let you know! Thanks a lot!!! :)